# Using hold on and hold off

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Context: Someone is messaging me on Whatsapp frequently and trying to get attention.  I can think of the following reply to ask him to wait for some time:

> Could you **hold off** for a few minutes
> Please **hold on** for some time

Not sure if I am using the "hold off" and "hold on" in the proper way.

Any suggestions or alternatives?

Comment: "Please hold on for some time" is not commonly said.  In addition to the usage @FubmbleFingers gives below, especially if you are speaking to someone on the telephone, it is common to hear "Please hold" - which I think is what you want here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if dictionaries will make the relatively subtle distinction clear, but...

> 1: *Could you **hold off** for a few minutes?*
> ...usually means...
> Please **refrain from doing** whatever you're doing / about to do (for a short time)
> OR ***stay back, keep away*** (nearly always, *temporarily*)

...whereas...

> 2: *Could you **hold on** for a few minutes?*
> ...usually means...
> Please **wait** for a short time

Obviously in many contexts there's actually no difference between ***refraining*** from doing something (which you may or may not *already* be doing when you're asked to "hold off"), and ***waiting*** (until the speaker does something).

If in doubt, though, you should probably use ***on***, since it works more naturally in a wider range of contexts (and it might be considered *rude* in some contexts to tell someone to stop doing something).

---

Note that a few centuries ago, ***Hold**!* could be used with no preposition as an imperative meaning *[You] Hold on! / Stay back!* a usage which has long since died out. But there is a *current* prepositionless usage whereby someone on the telephone says ***Please hold***, meaning ***Please wait** [while I put you "on hold"] until I can respond appropriately to your call*.

Comment: 'Hold off' could also carry a context of 'stay back' or 'stay away', 'don't go in [there] yet'. So I agree, 'hold on' is the simpler context-free version.

Comment: You're quite right, so I've added that. Of course, there's also the "repulse an attack" sense - *The gang members **held off** the police for several hours, but eventually they were all either shot or surrendered*. That would rarely be used as an imperative, but there's near-synonymous, *Sergeant! HQ says "**Hold out** until reinforcements arrive!"*

Comment: I did actually have the full 'armed response, police TV drama' scenario playing in my head as I typed the first comment ;)